# python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run the command `pip install scrapy`, it shows this error:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sbbmgfjk/cryptography/`

I have tried upgrading it using `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: paste the complete traceback

Answer (score 0):

It appears the cryptography package (as of today) now requires the addition of setuptools-rust, which depends on Rust and a bunch of new system libraries for duplicating all of the original cryptography calls.  This is a major pain and pip isn't being very helpful with a LIST OF NEW DEPS!

Grrr.

Here is the complete list of all the new crap I had to build to get ansible to install on a fresh system.  This is derived from my bash history while I worked through install attempts, review the errors, manually add more packages, lather rinse repeat for over an hour.

```
$ apt-get install zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev 
$ python3 -m venv ansible
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ python3 -m pip install pillow
$ python3 -m pip install rust
$ python3 -m pip install setuptools-rust
$ python3 -m pip install ansible

This is just what I had to add to what had been a functional ansible venv running again. Oh, and there was some apt-get install python3.8 and some update-alternatives crap going on, too.  That one python library is causing major headaches for ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
```